# Let P(x) be a polynomial of n degree , prove P(a)-p(b) is divisible by a-b

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Let  p(x) be a polynomial of n degree  prove that  p(a)-p(b) is divisible by a-b
My first thought was to substitute a and b in the place of x and form a general expression then try to prove it but I didnt get any answer afterward
Could anyone help me out

Comment: Are $P$ and $p$ the same polynomial?

Comment: Hint: try to prove $a-b|a^n-b^n$.

Comment: Alternative approach: show that $x-b\mid P(x)-P(b)$ as polynomials (also I assume that the polynomials should be in $\Bbb Z[x]$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: I tried but couldn't get to it anyone ?

Comment: @Aayatkhan induction.